# Restangular POST headers

Tags: angularjs, rest, restangular

I'm trying to send a post to a server, for auth I need to include a X-CSRF-Token which is requested separately (i have no control over this).

Currently I have this:

```
Restangular.all('rest/band/node').post($scope.dataObject, {}, {}, {'X-CSRF-Token': $scope.apitoken}).then(function (res) {
    console.log(res.data);
});
```

I end up with permission denied as the headers fail. If I stop the auth on the server, it'll post fine. Likewise if I test a REST post with the correct header token it works fine. However I can't get restangular to work at all.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: please provide the full error code. Is it an auth failure, or a CORS failure.

Comment: It's simply a 403, denied by the server.

Comment: and, on your server, what would cause a 403? not having the correct csrf token?

Comment: Lack of the auth token ('X-CSRF-Token').  This has to be set as a header in the post for it to work.

Comment: And, if you look at your network tab, is the header present in the request? according to docs you seem to be following the correct syntax.

Comment: Yeah it's there, sorry I should have though to check that first :) Not sure what's going on, I'm not in control of the server. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Next thing to test would be whether or not the token is correct then. for example, is it supposed to be encoded? Past that, i'm not sure what else could cause it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your call to match the below:

```
Restangular.one('rest/band').post('node', $scope.dataObject, {}, {'X-CSRF-Token': $scope.apitoken}).then(function (res) {
    console.log(res.data);
});
```

on a collection method (you have an extra dictionary in there):

```
Restangular.all('rest/band/node').post($scope.dataObject, {}, {'X-CSRF-Token': $scope.apitoken}).then(function (res) {
    console.log(res.data);
});
```

Restangular post functionality os dependent on collection or element methods. The names are the same and without knowing what you are posting, the difference between `.all` and `.one` can be significant

Comment: Turns out the issue was server side. However thank you for the correct syntax! The Restangular.one was what I should have been using.